# CPLEX Python- creating an objective function with quadratic term and linear term

Tags: python, optimization, cplex, quadratic-programming

CPLEX novice here. Sorry!

I am running CPLEX, through the python API and  I want to set the objective function that contains a quadratic term and a linear term ,and minimise.

Example below:

obj = aQ+bV

where a & b are scalar constants,
Q is the quadratic term
V is a vector.

Below is a specific example using dummy data.
I want to find x1,x2,x3 that minimises the following equation:

```
              Quadratic Part                                               Linear Part
```

[image: Quadratic and linear terms in objective function]

So far I can solve the quadratic part by explicitly writing out the quadratic matrix and running

p.objective.set_quadratic(Q)

How would I add the second linear term to this objective function?

Thanks,

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested:

The solution was really straight forward.

1. p.objective.set_quadratic(q) - this function sets the quadratic part of the objective, but it is not exsaustive, meaning you can add a linear term to the objective by simply including the line 2.
2. p.objective.set_linear() or as in my case adding the linear term in the variables section:
3. p.variables.add(obj= my_linear_objective, ub=upper_bounds, lb=lower_bounds, names=my_names)

Essentially here what youre doing is creating an objective that is a combination of your quadratic part set in line #1 + your linear part set in line 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

With docplex python you can directly use quadratic terms

See

https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zooquadratic.py

For tiny example